# how to get data from XML file?

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to get data from an XML file, I tried some code this one of them but I can't get the correct result.

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
    XmlD=etree.parse("MVI_20011.xml")
    root=XmlD.getroot()
    for child in root:
        print(child.get("density"),child.get("num"))
        for children in child:
            print(children.text)
```

This some lines of my XML file:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <sequence name="MVI_20011">
      <sequence_attribute camera_state="unstable" sence_weather="sunny"/>
      <ignored_region>
         <box left="778.75" top="24.75" width="181.75" height="63.5"/>
         <box left="930.75" top="94.75" width="29.75" height="33.5"/>
         <box left="523.75" top="13.75" width="178.5" height="37.5"/>
         <box left="207.75" top="34.75" width="270.5" height="94.5"/>
         <box left="182.75" top="131.75" width="145.5" height="117.5"/>
         <box left="0.5" top="231.75" width="88.75" height="121.5"/>
         <box left="123.75" top="151.75" width="57.5" height="97.5"/>
      </ignored_region>
      <frame density="7" num="1">
         <target_list>
            <target id="1">
               <box left="592.75" top="378.8" width="160.05" height="162.2"/>
               <attribute orientation="18.488" speed="6.859" trajectory_length="5" truncation_ratio="0.1" vehicle_type="car"/>
            </target>
            <target id="2">
               <box left="557.65" top="120.98" width="47.2" height="43.06"/>
               <attribute orientation="19.398" speed="1.5055" trajectory_length="72" truncation_ratio="0" vehicle_type="car"/>
            </target>
            <target id="3">
               <box left="545.2" top="88.27" width="35.25" height="30.08"/>
               <attribute orientation="2.7525" speed="0.5206" trajectory_length="105" truncation_ratio="0" vehicle_type="car"/>
               <occlusion>
                  <region_overlap left="553" top="88.27" width="27.45" height="1.52" occlusion_id="5" occlusion_status="1"/>
               </occlusion>
            </target>
            <target id="4">
               <box left="508.35" top="67.5" width="28.0" height="25.925"/>
               <attribute orientation="349.06" speed="0.52707" trajectory_length="132" truncation_ratio="0" vehicle_type="car"/>
            </target>
            <target id="5">
               <box left="553" top="70.095" width="29.55" height="19.695"/>
               <attribute orientation="58.543" speed="0.49822" trajectory_length="151" truncation_ratio="0" vehicle_type="car"/>
            </target>
            <target id="6">
               <box left="731.1" top="114.23" width="52.4" height="39.95"/>
               <attribute orientation="227.87" speed="2.2585" trajectory_length="91" truncation_ratio="0" vehicle_type="car"/>
            </target>
            <target id="7">
               <box left="902.15" top="250.12" width="58.85" height="107.99"/>
               <attribute orientation="197.29" speed="12.115" trajectory_length="157" truncation_ratio="0.3583" vehicle_type="car"/>
            </target>
         </target_list>
      </frame>
```

I want to get data for each frame I expected for the 1st frame :

```
(7,1) 
592.75 378.8 160.05 162.2
557.65 120.98 47.2 43.06
```

and the other box, I hope you get my problem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following approach:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

doc = ET.parse('input.xml')
root = doc.getroot()

for frame in root.findall('frame'):
    print((frame.get('density'), frame.get('num')))
    for box in frame.findall('.//box'):
        print(*box.attrib.values())
```

The output:

```
('7', '1')
592.75 378.8 160.05 162.2
557.65 120.98 47.2 43.06
545.2 88.27 35.25 30.08
508.35 67.5 28.0 25.925
553 70.095 29.55 19.695
731.1 114.23 52.4 39.95
902.15 250.12 58.85 107.99
```

Comment: thank you this is what I wanted. I am very grateful.

Comment: I got a problem with this code for each execution I got a different result, the values are not sorted can you help me to fix this issue?
thank you.

Comment: @oussamabousselmi, why did not you present all the needed conditions at start? while now that definitely seems to be an additional conditions.

Comment: I am a beginner at this, I didn't know that the result can change. I found how to get what I need thanks a lot for your help you solved my problem.

Comment: @oussamabousselmi, that does not mean that the beginner need to change the conditions infinitely in scope of the same question. You are able to initiate a new question increasing an experience of properly formulating a crucial problem and describing all conditions. (We don't get earnings from providing an answers)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the tag text but you want the attribute value.

Here is an example:

```py
XmlD.find(('.//frame')).attrib['density']

# this should return '7'
```

```py
for key, value in XmlD.find(('.//frame')).items():
    print(key, value)

# this should return
# density 7
# num 1
```

Comment: the main problem is how to get the data at  <box attribute: left,  top, width and height

Comment: see the edit. First you have to get the target id, then you the child's tag (box) attributes.